# How can you compile a Rust library to target asm.js?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, asm.js

I've got a Rust library with the following usual structure:

```
Cargo.toml
src
 |--lib.rs
.cargo
 |--config (specifies target=asmjs-unknown-emscripten)
target
 |......
```

When I do `cargo build`, I get a new directory under target called `asmjs-unknown-emscripten`, but the .js files that I'd expect are not there.

[As this user notes](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/compiling-to-the-web-with-rust-and-emscripten/7627/14), you've got to do something special to export functions to asm.js besides marking them public:

> Basically you have this boilerplate right now:
>
> ```
> #[link_args = "-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_hello_world']"]
> extern {}
>
> fn main() {}
>
> #[no_mangle]
> pub extern fn hello_world(n: c_int) -> c_int {
>     n + 1
> }
> ```
>
> Then you can use this in your javascript to access and call the function:
>
> ```
> var hello_world = cwrap('hello_world', 'number', ['number']);
>
> console.log(hello_world(41));
> ```

However, Rust complains about the `#[link_args...]` directive as deprecated.  Is there any documentation out there that can explain how this works?

Comment: Have you seen [Compiling Rust to your Browser](http://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/)?

Comment: Yeah, I skimmed it but I might be missing something.  The only code samples (in rust) I saw were just annotating public functions with #[no_mangle].  That doesn't seem to work on my end.  I noticed they were using rustc instead of cargo...?  This [link](http://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/demos/04-call-into-lib/) seems to be the source for the users comment above, but link_args is still deprecated -- and what's the deal with the empty main(){}?

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question! I was running into [similar dependency issues](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/777) with [fable](http://fable.io/).

I have checked [Compiling Rust to your Browser - Call from JavaScript](http://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/demos/04-call-into-lib/), [Advanced Linking - Link args](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/advanced-linking.html) and [How to pass cargo linker args](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-pass-cargo-linker-args/3163) however was not able to use `cargo` in the same way as [`rustc --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten call-into-lib.rs`](http://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/demos/04-call-into-lib/).

The closer I was able to get was to run both `cargo` and `rustc` like

```
cd lib1
cargo build --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten
rustc --target=asmjs-unknown-emscripten src\lib.rs
cd ..

cd lib2
cargo build --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten
rustc --target=asmjs-unknown-emscripten src\lib.rs --extern lib1=..\lib1\target\asmjs-unknown-emscripten\debug\liblib1.rlib
cd ..

cd lib3
cargo build --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten
rem rustc --target=asmjs-unknown-emscripten src\lib.rs --extern webplatform=..\lib3\target\asmjs-unknown-emscripten\debug\deps\libwebplatform-80d107ece17b262d.rlib
rem the line above fails with "error[E0460]: found possibly newer version of crate `libc` which `webplatform` depends on"
cd ..

cd app
cargo build --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten
cd ..
```

see the [so-41492672-rust-js-structure](https://github.com/davidpodhola/so-41492672-rust-js-structure/blob/master/build.cmd). It allows to have several libraries that compile together to the JavaScript in the final application.

I still think some manual linking would help. Would be interested to know.

P.S. to see what `rustc` uses to link, you can pass `-Z print-link-args` to it.